# GA ignores tags in utm tagged links

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

I have a problem with tagged traffic from one social network (`odnoklassniki.ru`).

All links in our latest posts are tagged and shortened by URL shortener of odnoklassniki (shortened link looks like `okey.link/jhlshG`).

I can see incomming tagged traffic from this links in real time reports in GA, but on the next day I can't find any session from source / medium = ok / smm.

No filters set in property.

I found the only one assumption: redirect from HTTPS to HTTP can cause this problem. Actually there are three redirects (HTTP -> HTTPS -> HTTP). But as far as I know it only applies to referer loss problem, not to ignoring `utm` tags (they passed correctly). And referer does not get lost in my case.

[image]

Did anyone face such problem?

Comment: Whether URL parameters (`utm` tags) get lost during a redirect is dependent on how the redirect is constructed. (But why two redirects?) If you can see the correct incoming traffic in real time then it would seem nothing is being lost?

Comment: Shortened links redirect 2 times. It is social network settings, i can change nothing about it. I use http sniffer to track redirections.
I cann't find traffic in regular report in GA, so all is being lost. )

Comment: Can you post the code that does the redirects?   There is probably a line in your *.htacess* file.

Comment: You can test link okey.link/39iU8
And as i said final link on landing page has all utm i need, but GA ignore them in regular reports but take them in real time report.

Comment: There could be a filter changing the campaign related dimensions. Try looking at the real-time Traffic Sources report in a View that has no filters.

Comment: Can you visit one of your redirects after opening the network tab of Firefox or Chrome developer tools and post the result?

Comment: @StephenBrown, I have discussed this issue with GA support for two weeks. They didn't say anything useful. They saw real time report and view without any filters and recommended me to ask social network support service. Redirect may cause this problem. Social net didn't respond yet.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, i don't know how to post log file on stackexchange. First three rows look like this:
3gIFK 307  Other 0 B 2 ms 
3gIFK 301 text/html http://okl.lt/3gIFK 614 B 56 ms 
?utm_medium=smm&utm_source=ok&utm_campaign=20160413_capricereview 200 document https://okl.lt/3gIFK 14.6 KB 492 ms

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, forgot to mention. There is only one (https to http) redirect now, but problem remains.

Comment: Take a screenshot of it, and post the screenshot please.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, [screen in Firefox](https://beta.postimg.org/image/jo0ivughl/).

Answer (score 2):

In your Google Analytics configuration, have you allowed manual UTM parameters to override auto-tagging?

You can find this option in the Property settings.

Comment: No, but problem is not about AdWords auto tagging. Odnoklassniki is absolutely different system. For now we're trying to put normal html link in posts, but it's problem too.

Comment: Another follow-up, if you just want to track from that one site, why not use Custom Groupings?

Comment: I lose important information due to tag ignorance. Custom groupings can do nothing about it.